# Binding dynamic objects wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to bind a custom object that can be dynamicaly changed to a displaed element.

My window.xaml has this for now :

```
<StackPanel Height="310" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="Configuration_stackPanel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="264" Grid.Column="1">
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Client}" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,0,0,0" Name="Client" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</StackPanel>
```

In window.xaml.cs, i've got member which is

```
public CustomObject B;
```

A CustomObject has a client member.
B.Client, gets the client name (which is a string) among other things

What should i do to display B.Client and have it change when it is change in the code.

ie : if in the code i do B.Client="foo" then foo is displayed
and if i do B.Client="bar", bar is displayed instead of foo.

Thanks in advance
F

Comment: can you provide the definition of CustomObject please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CustomObject` class must implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface:

```
public class CustomObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _client;
    public string Client
    {
        get { return _client; }
        set
        {
            _client = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Client");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't i have to add something in the xaml to tell it where to look for  Client ?

Comment: You just need to bind to the property. The binding will be updated automatically when the value changes.

Comment: It doesn't work this is why i ask. Shouldn't i add something like StaticResource or something else i the xaml ?

Comment: The thing is that i'm not really sure how window.xaml can find B ?

Comment: @djfoxmccloud, just set B as the `DataContext` of the Window; I assumed it was already the case...

Comment: Thank for the reply. I added it. But i get an error : "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Client' property not found on 'object'"

Comment: Ok i found the problem ! I tried to use datacontext in the xaml. In fact i had to set it in the code after the window is loaded ! thanks